# generate a page of news with one query with Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I would like to generate a page of news with associated tags with one query. But I can't get it right. What I don't understand is why the line juste above the line with the error is correct according to Idea editor and the compiler.

```
  val newsTable = TableQuery[NewsTable]
  val newsTagsTable = TableQuery[NewsTags]
  val newsTagsAssociationsTable = TableQuery[newsTagsAssociations]//2 columns: newsId and tagId

  case class FullNews(news:Option[News],tags:Seq[NewsTag])

  def getPage(page: Long = 0, pageSize: Int = 10): Future[Page[FullNews]] = {
    val offset = pageSize * page
    val total = newsTable.size.result
    val selectedNews = newsTable.sortBy(x => x.id.desc).drop(offset).take(pageSize)

    val fullNews = selectedNews.result.map(a => a.map(news => {

      val tagsId = newsTagsAssociationsTable.filter(x => x.idNews === news.id).map(_.idTag)
      val tagsQuery =  newsTagsTable.filter(tag => tag.id in tagsId)
      for (tags <- tagsQuery .result) yield FullNews(Some(news), tags)
    }))

    val theFullNews: Future[Seq[FullNews]] = db.run(fullNews )//error at this line
    val totalFuture = db.run(total)

    for (
      newsSeq <- theFullNews;
      t <- totalFuture
    ) yield Page[FullNews](newsSeq, page, offset, t, pageSize)

  }
```

the play compiler says :

> Blockquote
>   type mismatch;
>   [error]  found   : slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Seq[slick.dbio.DBIOAction[models.FullNews,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Read]],slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Read]
>   [error]  required: slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Seq[models.FullNews],slick.dbio.NoStream,Nothing]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is typically solved by using joins. I'm assuming not every `news` has `tags`. That's why I'm going to use an `outer join`. Untested code:

```
// FullNews always has a news, right? Removed option type.
case class FullNews(news: News, tags: Seq[NewsTag])

def getPage(page: Long = 0, pageSize: Int = 10): Future[Page[FullNews]] = {
  val offset = pageSize * page

  // let's query fullNews first. 
  // fullNews is basically Query[Seq[News, Option[NewsTag]]]
  val fullNews = newsTable.sortBy(x => x.id.desc).drop(offset).take(pageSize)
    .joinLeft(newsTagsAssociationsTable).on(_.id === _.newsId)
    .joinLeft(newsTagsTable).on(_._2.map(_.tagId) === _.id)
    .map {
      case ((news, _), tag) => (news, tag)
    }

  // query the total size
  val totalNews = newsTable.size

  // Now that we have our queries in place, create an action
  // and map the result to FullNews:
  val fullNewsAction = fullNews.result.map { result => 
    result.groupBy(_._1).map {
      case (news, grp) => FullNews(news, grp.flatMap(_._2).distinct)
    }
  }

  // For the sake of completeness, let's also create an action for totalNews
  val totalNewsAction = totalNews.result

  // Compose an action consisting of fullNewsAction and totalNewsAction
  val pageAction = for {
    n <- fullNewsAction
    t <- totalNewsAction
  } yield Page(n, page, offset, t, pageSize)

  // Finally execute pageAction on the db
  db.run(pageAction.transactionally)
}
```

If every `news` has at least one `tag` associated, you could replace the outer join with an inner join. See [slick docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/queries.html#joining-and-zipping) for further information.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly, there is just a typo at the  "val fullNewsAction" line (the second map is unnecessary)

Comment: Now I am wondering how to get only news containing a specific NewTag. I have found a way but with that solution I do not get the other tags displayed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure, but by inner joining and filtering `tags`, `newsTagsAssociation` and `news` should get you a list of news that contains a specific tag. Then inner join that news list again with `newsTagsAssociation` and `tags`. The result should now contain all tags for your list of news. By the way: If your original problem is solved you should ask a new question for your new problem. Maybe someone will find it useful too :)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have thought too and it works too :D. Will post the solution in a new Question when I will have more time to do it.